# In EF Code First, How to have ApplicationUser UserId as foreign key in a custom entity?

Tags: sql, ef-code-first

My Custom Entity:

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key,Column(Order=0)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        //Other properties
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
     }
```

ApplicationUser Class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //one to many relation
    public virtual List<Sandwich.Order>Order { get; set; }

   public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
   GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager){..}
}
```

I have two DbContexts (One default of AppUser and One I created):

```
  public class ADbContext : DbContext
{
    public ADbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Toppings> ToppingsDbset { get; set;}
    //I had to comment the line below to in order to work with ToppingDBset but then I can't work with OrderDBSet
    //public DbSet<Order> OrderDbSet { get; set; }

}
//Default AppDbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I run it just working with ApplicationDbContext it works fine and creates following table with all the relationships.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlfCX.png)

My problem: is when I try to work with ADbContext with un-commented `public DbSet<Order> OrderDbSet { get; set; }`

{"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\n.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\n.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined

Solutions I tried:

```
//Adding following method on ADbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

I am trying to have all tables created in one Database. I am using EF6.

Answer (score 0):

try this in OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder):

> modelBuilder.Entity()
>           .HasMany(c => c.Order)
>           .WithOne(e => e.ApplicationUser);

[refrence](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

In DbContext file, I added OrderDbSet within ApplicationDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Order> OrderDbset { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
 }
```